# Is an old mtb with replaced gear safe to buy?

Tags: mountain-bike

I believe this question to be on topic for this site, I want it to be more factual based than opinion, another similar question is [this one](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/21473/is-it-a-good-idea-to-buy-a-7-year-old-mtb). If its not feel free to close it.

I am looking at buying an older (10 yrs old) Giant NRS 1 MTB, it has very good [reviews](http://www.mtbr.com/cat/bikes/xc-suspensio/giant/nrs-1/prd_363242_1526crx.aspx) for the frame especially, but other parts have been replaced (it has a new front wheel, cables etc.). Should I be worried that other parts will be about to fall off, or are replacements a good thing?

**EDIT:** *Ok so the wheel was replaced due to hitting a stump at night time, the cables were getting old, it has had plenty of action, but was well looked after. The rear sus has a tiny bit of play in the top bush (not enough to realise when riding)*

It also has a leaking front fork, not a big issue (probably new seal, or not worry), but makes me wonder if it is worth it, will cost around $400 US ish, do you think it will have other issues?

cheers in advance!

Comment: Which bike is it? You said it has good reviews online, but don't link to any of them. It's hard to give an assessment with so little information.

Comment: @PaulH Ok will edit question, was looking for a general thought but will link to it.

Comment: To quality what @PaulH says, it's hard to give an assessment without seeing the actual bike, unfortunately. There is no silver bullet, you just have to gen up and know what to look for. There are several previous questions on here that can help you.

Comment: The concern with the front wheel "replaced due to hitting a stump" would be that the fork was damaged or (in extreme cases) the frame was bent.  The leakage reenforces the suspicion of fork damage.  But there's certainly nothing wrong with having cables replaced -- that's necessary on bikes every 10K miles/10 years or so and is simply a "scheduled maintenance" sort of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a mountain bike parts do wear out. I would be more cautious of a 10 year old bike with original parts unless it had original tires and I could still see the manufacturer 'tags' (i.e. like new) showing it had been ridden only once or twice and been a garage ornament for all but the first 2 weeks of its life.

If the bike has been ridden regularly you will be wanting a well maintained one. This means parts replaced as they wear out or get damaged.

I have bough several second hand MTB's - you get a better bike for you money than new. The ones I have always ended up buying have had many parts replaced, as its these bikes that the riders are using regularity and keeping well tuned and maintained.

With respect to the edits - a leaking front fork could simply need a new seal or it could be a new fork - its a deal breaker for me.

Answer (score 2):

Aluminum fatigues.  A 10 year of bike with a lot of miles could be getting towards the end of it life.

It has a modern headset.

Full suspension has come a long way in 10 years.

But 26" wheels.
I would rather have a hard tail 29".

You would have to judge the parts based on inspection.

With a leaky fork I would not do it period. 
How do you know it is not a big issues? 
Do you have a quote that it is a cheap repair?

To me that is not the kind of bike you put a lot of money into.

Comment: The leaky fork is due to fluid working its way through the ports of the fork, I don't think it's a big issue however. Don't have a quote though

Comment: Even if you fix the fork for $40 you still have a 26".  And a new nice fork is $300 and now you have $700 into a 26".  Yes it is more money but a 29" hard tail with tubeless is a lot nicer bike.